# css - em value gives two different px values for the same element

Tags: css, firefox, chromium

An HTML element has its border and position set with equal, but opposite, em values. However, the px values this results in are different between the two properties (per the element inspector).

In Firefox 53, `0.4 em` turns into `4.6667 px` for the border, and `5.2 px` for the position.

In Chromium 58, `0.4 em` turns into `6.39844 px` for the border, and `6.4 px` for the position.

This is for the same element, so the `font-size` property isn't even different in either calculation. And I have observed this for a rather long time (since 2015 at least) in both browsers, and on different elements with these properties applied. Scouring Google gives nothing, and I don't know if I'm the only one with this problem.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  border: 0.4em solid;
  right: -0.4em;
}
```

```html
<ul>test
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I'm quite interested in finding out more about this technique of setting `position` in `px` or `em`. Always eager to learn something new.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu well the element has `position: absolute` and its parent has `position: relative` (or maybe the other way around - all I know is that the positioning on the two are different). Other than that I don't know what you were expecting me to add...

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://i.imgur.com/AjL0YlN.png / http://i.imgur.com/UbgzbNy.png — border is the same (except Firefox rounds to an integer in the inspector) in both cases.

Comment: @Quentin and what were the positions?